# Computer Randomly Restart Itself While Playing Certain Games

Tags: graphics, wine, games

I have this problem for some time. While playing certain games (which are not intensive), my computer randomly restarts.

To me it seems that somehow GPU shuts down... I don't know.

Some games work perfectly. For example I have a lots of hours playing GTA 5 and not a single crash or lag. While some games that are not "hard" for hardware, like Stronghold: Warlords causing often crashes followed by system reboot.

I tried to find similar problems online, but what I don't understand is that, GTA 5 and Witcher 3 are more intensive for hardware that Stronghold (for example), but the third game causing crashes.

It is always the same and after some time reboot. During that screen, computer is not responding to any command.

I was thinking that it may be something related to GPU Driver...

[image]

OS: Ubuntu 21.10

RAM: 16GB / SWAP 2GB

CPU: AMD® Ryzen 7 2700x eight-core processor × 16

GPU: Radeon RX 590

As per suggestion, here is a log from `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` command:

```
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu at-spi2-registr[1804]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable t>
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu at-spi2-registr[1804]: Unable to register client with session manager
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu systemd[1525]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu systemd[1525]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dsession\x2dquit-12756.scope: Deactivated successfully.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:39 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:40 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-session-binary[1648]: Entering running state
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu at-spi2-registr[1804]: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable t>
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu at-spi2-registr[1804]: Unable to register client with session manager
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu systemd[1525]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu systemd[1525]: app-gnome-gnome\x2dsession\x2dquit-12762.scope: Deactivated successfully.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
дец 27 20:17:41 ubuntu gnome-shell[1666]: amdgpu: The CS has been cancelled because the context is lost.
```

Comment: take a look in your system logs so you can see what did happen.

Comment: How much RAM/Swap does `free` show? [Edit] your Question to add information.

Comment: After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, or an intentional reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Comment: I was able to reproduce error again. This time by just exiting to main menu of a game and wait for about 5-10 minutest. So, Nothing intensive for a hardware. I will paste log from a sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e into question. This time I needed to restart computer manually, so I hope that it didnt mess the log.

Comment: Does this only happen with Windows games? If so, you should possibly troubleshoot each game individually. Windows games are not designed to run on Linux so they rely on emulation. Each game can have its own quirks to get it running on Linux smoothly. Many Windows games just won't work properly on Linux and may not have much support.  This can be particularly true of games from smaller developers or games that don't have a huge base of players who are running the software on Linux using Windows emulation.